# Why universal instantiation cannot be used here?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a following sentence:

> $$\forall x~(Fx \to \forall y~(Fy \to Gy)) ~\vdash~ \forall x~(Fx \to Gx) $$

Why I cannot use UI twice and get:

> $$Fa \rightarrow (Fa \rightarrow Ga) $$

This is my proof:

1) $\forall x~(Fx \to \forall y~(Fy \to Gy))$

$\quad$2) $Fa \to (Fa \to Ga)$

$\qquad$3) $Fa$ (Assumption)

$\qquad$4) $Ga$ (From 2,3)

$\quad$5) $Fa \to Ga$

6) $\forall x~(Fx \to Gx) $

And the second line was marked as the wrong one by somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot?

Comment: It was marked as the wrong one so I am wondering too

Comment: Then maybe you should provide the complete deduction you wrote and how you tried applying UI.

Comment: I updated mine but only the second line was marked as the wrong one

Comment: What does the slash in your first formula mean?

Comment: It means that I have to prove that one can be derived from the premise

Comment: @ThaiDoan use  `\vdash` for $\vdash$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  This is not a duplicate of that question; though it is *somewhat* related.

Comment: I tentatively think this question isn't completely a duplicate because the "here" is substantially different: different enough that in this case the result is correct just the steps to get there weren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI allows us to deduce $\phi$ from  $(\forall x)(\phi)$ and nothing more.

In your case, it seems like you have tried to deduce $Fa\to \phi$ from $Fa\to (\forall y)(\phi)$ with a single application of UI. This is an invalid use of UI.

Comment: But I did apply UI twice to get the second line (by saying UIx2, we are allowed to do that)

Comment: To apply UI twice in one line, you must be deducing $\phi$ from $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\phi)$, which is not what you did. Both universal quantifiers *must* be on the outside of the expression.

Comment: so that means if one universal quantifier is inside I have to write separately my UI application?

Comment: UI only lets you remove universal quantifiers on the outside of expressions. To remove the inner one, you would have to somehow whittle down the expression (until the inner quantifier is on the outside) using other means before handling the quantifier.

Comment: Oh, I got it why I cannot use UI twice here. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting one of the answers to show that your question has been resolved :)

Comment: @AustinWeaver,  I think that use in this case UI twice is allowed but not in the way ThaiDoan does. See my answer.

Comment: @Gödel I acknowledged that that was the case in my second comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Universal Instantiation(Elimination) twice.   You just cannot do it immediately.   You must instantiate the universal $x$, raise the assumption of $Fa$, modus ponens, and *then* instantiate the universal $y$ (to the same arbitrary $a$).   After that your proof continues as you wanted.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{1.\quad \forall x~(Fx\to \forall y~(Fy\to Gy))\quad\text{Premise} }{\fitch{[a]}{2.\quad Fa \to(\forall y~(Fy\to Gy))\quad~~1,\forall\text{Elim}\\\fitch{3.\quad Fa\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad~~\text{Assume}}{4.\quad \forall y~(Fy\to Gy)\qquad\qquad~~~2,3,\to\text{Elim (modus ponens)}\\ 5.\quad Fa\to Ga\qquad\qquad\qquad~~~ 4,\forall\text{Elim}\\6.\quad Ga\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad~~ 3,5,\to\text{Elim}}\\7.\quad Fa\to Ga\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad~3,6\to\text{Intro}}\\8.\quad \forall x~(Fx\to Gx)\qquad\qquad\quad~~ 7,\forall\text{Intro}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Universal instantiation says 
$$
\forall_x\phi(x)\Rightarrow\phi(a)
$$
So, in your case you can get
$$
Fa\Rightarrow\forall_y(Fy\Rightarrow Gy)
$$
But, you have by UI that $\forall_y(Fy\Rightarrow Gy)\Rightarrow(Fa\Rightarrow Ga)$ so, by transitivity, $Fa\Rightarrow(Fa\Rightarrow Ga)$